# How can I get stock quotes using Google Finance API?

Tags: java, php, javascript, google-api, google-finance

I'm looking for access to financial data from Google services.

I found [this URL](http://finance.google.com/finance/info?client=ig&q=NASDAQ:MSFT) that gets the stock data for Microsoft.

What are all the possible parameters that Google allows for this kind of HTTP request? I'd like to see all the different information that I could get.

Comment: How did you find that URL?

Comment: You can easily get Google Finance data via YQL which is simple and REST based. An example can be found here: http://www.jarloo.com/google-finance-and-yql/

Comment: This is a great question, are there more answers that are up to date?

Comment: @Timmyc- The `client=ig` parametet leads me to believe this is/was used for an iGoogle widget. Just a guess though.

Comment: Note that if your application is [for public consumption, using the Google Finance API is against Google's terms of service](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/google-finance-apis/O8fjsgnamHE/-ZKSjif4yDIJ). @timmyc: the `&client` parameter isn't necessary. http://finance.google.com/finance/info?q=NASDAQ%3aMSFT works.

Comment: Cannot edit my previous comment due to protection, but that API is dead. Here is the new one http://www.jarloo.com/real-time-google-stock-api/

Comment: Java or JavaScript?

Comment: Google Finance API is no longer available. Great free alternatives are AlphaVantage.co and Intrinio (as at 2019)

Answer (score 41, accepted):

There's a whole API for managing portfolios. *Link removed. Google no longer provides a developer API for this.

Getting stock quotes is a little harder.  I found one article where someone got stock quotes using Google Spreadsheets.

You can also use the [gadgets](http://googlefinanceblog.blogspot.com/2007/10/api-gadgets-and-tabs-oh-my.html) but I guess that's not what you're after.

The API you mention is interesting but doesn't seem to be documented (as far as I've been able to find anyway).

Here is some information on [historical prices](http://computerprogramming.suite101.com/article.cfm/an_introduction_to_google_finance), just for reference sake.

Comment: There is an undocumented API from google you can use to get stock info much easier as it's REST based and doesn't require authentication. Here is a C# example http://www.jarloo.com/google-stock-api/

Comment: Note: The Google Finance API has been officially deprecated as of May 26, 2011 and will be shut down on October 20, 2012.

Comment: This answer is mostly off-topic. The answer below it is the correct one.

Answer (score 77):

The [Google Finance Gadget API](https://web.archive.org/web/20111209142224/http://code.google.com/apis/finance/docs/finance-gadgets.html) has been officially [deprecated since October 2012](http://googlecode.blogspot.com/2011/05/spring-cleaning-for-some-of-our-apis.html), <strike>but as of April 2014, it's still active.</strike> It is completely dead as of March 2022.

<strike>http://www.google.com/finance/info?q=NASDAQ:GOOG  
http://www.google.com/finance/info?q=CURRENCY:GBPUSD  
http://finance.google.com/finance/info?client=ig&q=AAPL,YHOO</strike>

You can also get charts: https://www.google.com/finance/getchart?q=YELP

**Note that if your application is for [public consumption, using the Google Finance API is against Google's terms of service](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/google-finance-apis/O8fjsgnamHE/-ZKSjif4yDIJ).**

Check [google-finance-get-stock-quote-realtime](http://digitalpbk.com/stock/google-finance-get-stock-quote-realtime) for the complete code in python

Comment: This led me exactly to what I was looking for!  Thanks.

Comment: But I cannot get the volume traded through this URL, Can you help me out, if I need the volume details too

Comment: @DanDascalescu Thanks Dan.  Looks like it was just down when I was checking it.  Comment deleted.

Comment: Awesome! Google thanks for existing and making this public!! Saint Google!

Comment: Thanks, still relevant today in Sep 2016

Comment: I'm sad to say that as of Sept 2017, those links are 404ing.

Answer (score 17):

I found this site helpful.

http://benjisimon.blogspot.com/2009/01/truly-simple-stock-api.html

It links to an API yahoo seems to offer that is very simple and useful.

For instance:

http://finance.yahoo.com/d/quotes.csv?s=GOOG+AAPL&f=snl1

Full details here:

http://www.gummy-stuff.org/Yahoo-data.htm

Comment: In yahoo to get that using curl  `curl -L "http://finance.yahoo.com/d/quotes.csv?s=msft&f=sl1d1t1c1ohgv&e=.csv"` . In curl `-L` is needed otherwise it will not work

Comment: No longer accepted or supported

Answer (score 11):

Edit: the api call has been removed by google. so it is no longer functioning.

Agree with Pareshkumar's answer. Now there is a python wrapper [googlefinance](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/googlefinance/0.4) for the url call.

Install googlefinance

```
$pip install googlefinance
```

It is easy to get current stock price:

```
>>> from googlefinance import getQuotes
>>> import json
>>> print json.dumps(getQuotes('AAPL'), indent=2)
[
  {
    "Index": "NASDAQ", 
    "LastTradeWithCurrency": "129.09", 
    "LastTradeDateTime": "2015-03-02T16:04:29Z", 
    "LastTradePrice": "129.09", 
    "Yield": "1.46", 
    "LastTradeTime": "4:04PM EST", 
    "LastTradeDateTimeLong": "Mar 2, 4:04PM EST", 
    "Dividend": "0.47", 
    "StockSymbol": "AAPL", 
    "ID": "22144"
  }
]
```

Google finance is a source that provides real-time stock data. There are also other APIs from yahoo, such as [yahoo-finance](https://github.com/lukaszbanasiak/yahoo-finance), but they are delayed by 15min for NYSE and NASDAQ stocks.

Comment: nice real time, what i was looking for!

Answer (score 4):

The problem with Yahoo and Google data is that it violates terms of service if you're using it for commercial use. When your site/app is still small it's not biggie, but as soon as you grow a little you start getting cease and desists from the exchanges.
A licensed solution example is FinancialContent: http://www.financialcontent.com/json.php
or [Xignite](http://www.xignite.com)

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps of interest, the Google Finance API documentaton includes [a section detailing how to access different parameters via JavaScript](http://code.google.com/apis/finance/docs/finance-gadgets.html#Raw_Data).

I suppose the JavaScript API might be a wrapper to the JSON request you mention above... perhaps you could check which HTTP requests are being sent.

Answer (score 3):

This is no longer an active API for google, you can try Xignite, although they charge: http://www.xignite.com

Answer (score 3):

The simplest way as you have explained is this [link](https://www.google.com/finance?q=INDEXDJX:.DJI) this is for 
'Dow Jones Industrial Average'

[Link 2](https://www.google.com/finance?q=INDEXNASDAQ:NDX) is for 'NASDAQ-100'

and for all related to NASDAQ [link 3](https://www.google.com/finance?q=NASDAQ)

I think this should be it, else you want same in JSON notations the same as Microsoft

Please refer this [old post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6335121/google-finance-how-to-get-the-json-data-streamed) I think this will help,

Update:

To know the details of volume and other details,
I have created a vbscript that is using IE object to fetch details from the link, and alerts the content in the particular id(Create a .vbs file and run it..

```
Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
while IE.readyState = 4: WScript.Sleep 10: wend
IE.Navigate "https://www.google.com/finance?q=INDEXNASDAQ%3ANDX&sq=NASDAQ&sp=2&ei=B3UoUsiIH5DIlgPEsQE"
IE.visible = true
while IE.readyState = 4: WScript.Sleep 10: wend
dim ht
ht= IE.document.getElementById("market-data-div").innerText
msgBox ht
IE.quit
```

this will alert the values from page
like this

```
3,124.54 0.00 (0.00%)
Sep 4 - Close
INDEXNASDAQ real-time data - Disclaimer
Range       -
52 week 2,494.38 - 3,149.24
Open        -
Vol.    0.00
```

I am sure this will help..

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer.
But I need the realtime data in json along with the volume traded, is there any rest services?

Comment: Please refer this for details on realtime, generally this links provide reatime data with some exception.. https://www.google.com/googlefinance/disclaimer/#realtime

Comment: Thanks once again bro, This one was really helpful, but still how can I get the volume information?

Comment: Its if you are aware of VBA or VBS on the page(https://www.google.com/finance?q=INDEXNASDAQ%3ANDX&sq=NASDAQ&sp=2&ei=B3UoUsiIH5DIlgPEsQE) the element's id is 'market-data-div' that div contains 2 more divs and the second div has the table that contains volume `<td class="val">759.30M</td>` like this. If want more help please post some code of your work or fiddle will do.

Comment: No Sir, Dont have any idea of VBA or VBS, but will check this definitely, Can you provide me the URL, which results in the realtime stock quote along with volume information?

Comment: I will create a fiddle for a with a js file which will alert you give me some time

Comment: Sure Sir, Thanks a lot and that will be of great help.. :-)
god bless you

Comment: @SashiKant I have updated my answer, Please find the VBS code that works well on windows PC enjoy :)

Comment: You are always welcome :) StackOverflow is there to help us all :)

Answer (score 2):

Here is an example that you can use. Havent got Google Finance yet, but Here is the Yahoo Example. You will need the [HTMLAgilityPack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/) , Which is awesome. Happy Symbol Hunting.

Call the procedure by using `YahooStockRequest(string Symbols);`

Where Symbols = a comma-delimited string of symbols, or just one symbol

```
public string YahooStockRequest(string Symbols,bool UseYahoo=true)
        {
            {
                string StockQuoteUrl = string.Empty;

                try
                {
                    // Use Yahoo finance service to download stock data from Yahoo
                    if (UseYahoo)
                    {
                        string YahooSymbolString = Symbols.Replace(",","+");
                        StockQuoteUrl = @"http://finance.yahoo.com/q?s=" + YahooSymbolString + "&ql=1";
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        //Going to Put Google Finance here when I Figure it out.
                    }

                    // Initialize a new WebRequest.
                    HttpWebRequest webreq = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(StockQuoteUrl);
                    // Get the response from the Internet resource.
                    HttpWebResponse webresp = (HttpWebResponse)webreq.GetResponse();
                    // Read the body of the response from the server.

                    HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
                    string pageSource;
                    using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(webresp.GetResponseStream()))
                    {
                        pageSource = sr.ReadToEnd();
                    }
                    doc.LoadHtml(pageSource.ToString());
                    if (UseYahoo)
                    {
                        string Results=string.Empty;
                        //loop through each Symbol that you provided with a "," delimiter
                        foreach (string SplitSymbol in Symbols.Split(new char[] { ',' }))
                        {
                            Results+=SplitSymbol + " : " + doc.GetElementbyId("yfs_l10_" + SplitSymbol).InnerText + Environment.NewLine;
                        }
                        return (Results);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        return (doc.GetElementbyId("ref_14135_l").InnerText);
                    }

                }
                catch (WebException Webex)
                {
                    return("SYSTEM ERROR DOWNLOADING SYMBOL: " + Webex.ToString());

                }

            }
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

Building upon the shoulders of giants...here's a one-liner I wrote to zap all of Google's current stock data into local Bash shell variables:

```
stock=$1 

# Fetch from Google Finance API, put into local variables
eval $(curl -s "http://www.google.com/ig/api?stock=$stock"|sed 's/</\n</g' |sed '/data=/!d; s/ data=/=/g; s/\/>/; /g; s/</GF_/g' |tee /tmp/stockprice.tmp.log)

echo "$stock,$(date +%Y-%m-%d),$GF_open,$GF_high,$GF_low,$GF_last,$GF_volume"
```

Then you will have variables like $GF_last $GF_open $GF_volume etc. readily available. Run env or see inside /tmp/stockprice.tmp.log

```
http://www.google.com/ig/api?stock=TVIX&output=csv by itself returns:

<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xml_api_reply version="1">
<finance module_id="0" tab_id="0" mobile_row="0" mobile_zipped="1" row="0" section="0" >
<symbol data="TVIX"/>
<pretty_symbol data="TVIX"/>
<symbol_lookup_url data="/finance?client=ig&amp;q=TVIX"/>
<company data="VelocityShares Daily 2x VIX Short Term ETN"/>
<exchange data="AMEX"/>
<exchange_timezone data="ET"/>
<exchange_utc_offset data="+05:00"/>
<exchange_closing data="960"/>
<divisor data="2"/>
<currency data="USD"/>
<last data="57.45"/>
<high data="59.70"/>
<low data="56.85"/>

etc.
```

So for `stock="FBM"` **/tmp/stockprice.tmp.log**  (and your environment) will contain:

```
GF_symbol="FBM"; 
GF_pretty_symbol="FBM"; 
GF_symbol_lookup_url="/finance?client=ig&amp;q=FBM"; 
GF_company="Focus Morningstar Basic Materials Index ETF"; 
GF_exchange="NYSEARCA"; 
GF_exchange_timezone=""; 
GF_exchange_utc_offset=""; 
GF_exchange_closing=""; 
GF_divisor="2"; 
GF_currency="USD"; 
GF_last="22.82"; 
GF_high="22.82"; 
GF_low="22.82"; 
GF_volume="100"; 
GF_avg_volume=""; 
GF_market_cap="4.56"; 
GF_open="22.82"; 
GF_y_close="22.80"; 
GF_change="+0.02"; 
GF_perc_change="0.09"; 
GF_delay="0"; 
GF_trade_timestamp="8 hours ago"; 
GF_trade_date_utc="20120228"; 
GF_trade_time_utc="184541"; 
GF_current_date_utc="20120229"; 
GF_current_time_utc="033534"; 
GF_symbol_url="/finance?client=ig&amp;q=FBM"; 
GF_chart_url="/finance/chart?q=NYSEARCA:FBM&amp;tlf=12"; 
GF_disclaimer_url="/help/stock_disclaimer.html"; 
GF_ecn_url=""; 
GF_isld_last=""; 
GF_isld_trade_date_utc=""; 
GF_isld_trade_time_utc=""; 
GF_brut_last=""; 
GF_brut_trade_date_utc=""; 
GF_brut_trade_time_utc=""; 
GF_daylight_savings="false";
```

Comment: Can I use the URL for a Real Time stock quote?

Comment: Mostly yes. Compare `GF_trade_time_utc` to the current time/date and you be the judge.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but here the volume is not coming in the json, is there any other way or URL to get the volume traded?

Answer (score 2):

The Google stock quote API has gone away. However, [Investor's Exchange offers an API](https://iextrading.com/developer/docs/) that's very easy to use for quote data.

Answer (score 1):

I have personally built an app for stock data and fundamentals with [Intrinio](https://intrinio.com/) Two years ago but abandoned the project because I was beaten to market by a competitor.

I built it in Java but they support multiple stacks. Back then, You could access their api for free for testing purposes, but I think they build packages based on your needs now.

In any case, they were exceptionally helpful and charge low fees from what I remember, and their library is well documented so pulling data in json is very straightforward.

Answer (score 0):

In order to find chart data using the financial data API of Google, one must simply go to Google as if looking for a search term, type finance into the search engine, and a link to Google finance will appear. Once at the Google finance search engine, type the ticker name into the financial data API engine and the result will be displayed. However, it should be noted that all Google finance charts are delayed by 15 minutes, and at most can be used for a better understanding of the ticker's past history, rather than current price.

A solution to the delayed chart information is to obtain a real-time financial data API. An example of one would be the barchartondemand interface that has real-time quote information, along with other detailed features that make it simpler to find the exact chart you're looking for. With fully customizable features, and specific programming tools for the precise trading information you need, barchartondemand's tools outdo Google finance by a wide margin.

Answer (score -2):

Try with this:
http://finance.google.com/finance/info?client=ig&q=NASDAQ:GOOGL

It will return you all available details about the mentioned stock.

e.g. out put would look like below:

```
// [ {
"id": "694653"
,"t" : "GOOGL"
,"e" : "NASDAQ"
,"l" : "528.08"
,"l_fix" : "528.08"
,"l_cur" : "528.08"
,"s": "0"
,"ltt":"4:00PM EST"
,"lt" : "Dec 5, 4:00PM EST"
,"lt_dts" : "2014-12-05T16:00:14Z"
,"c" : "-14.50"
,"c_fix" : "-14.50"
,"cp" : "-2.67"
,"cp_fix" : "-2.67"
,"ccol" : "chr"
,"pcls_fix" : "542.58"
}
]
```

You can have your company stock symbol at the end of this URL to get its details:

```
http://finance.google.com/finance/info?client=ig&q=<YOUR COMPANY STOCK SYMBOL>
```

Comment: Currently, the link leads to a 404 error.