# How to pick the title of a remote webpage

Tags: javascript, html

How I can read the title of a **remote** web page with javascript? Suppose the web page is:

```
www.google.com
```

I want to read the title of that page; how should I do this?

Comment: You want to find the title of the *current* page, or of a page at some remote domain?

Comment: "pick" is totally the wrong word here.

Comment: No i want to get the title of a remote page

Comment: @Ajay The question is not a basic as it looks. But it would still have been possible to find the answer via searching..

Comment: @PriyankPatel jQuery ain't gonna help; it's just not possible (unless aided by server-side)

Comment: r u using PHP ?? see this [link](http://www.tildemark.com/getting-website-title-and-description/)

Answer (score 4):

You won't be able to get this data with jQuery alone, however you can use jQuery to communicate with PHP, or some other server-side language that can do the heavy lifting for you. For instance, suppose we have the following in a PHP script on our server:

```
<?php # getTitle.php

    if ( $_POST["url"] ) {
        $doc = new DOMDocument();
        @$doc->loadHTML( file_get_contents( $_POST["url"] ) );
        $xpt = new DOMXPath( $doc );
        $output = $xpt->query("//title")->item(0)->nodeValue;
    } else {
        $output = "URL not provided";
    }

    echo $output;

?>
```

With this, we could have the following jQuery:

```
$.post("getTitle.php", { url:'http://example.com' }, function( data ) {
    alert(data);
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Getting the content of a remote page you have no control over is going to be a problem because of the same-origin-policy. For more information look here: [How to get the content of a remote page with JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1304653/how-to-get-the-content-of-a-remote-page-with-javascript)

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
alert(document.title);
```

in your case i guess you would only be using the `document.title`

Comment: The poster wants the title of a remote page.

Answer (score -1):

The effective method is to write some Server side code (using PHP/ASP/.NET) and pass the URL via AJAX in script and get the title of any remote page.