# add parameter to google query

Tags: php, json, parsing, google-search

I am trying to get the realtime stockquotes from google for some time now.
First I try'd the finance api, but that didd'nt work out.

Then I saw this query and it seems to good to be true

```
http://www.google.com/finance/info?client=ig&q=goog
```

It must have some drawbacks that I am not aware off now.

Anyway, it does give realtime, at least that what it is says on the google finance page

Does anyone know if I can add more parameters for the query like + YAHOO (this is falty)
so I can get more then one stock??

Also, is the output in json or do Y have to parse it differently?
I was planning to do this with curl and ajax

thanks, Richard

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just add more ticker symbols with a comma, as in:

http://www.google.com/finance/info?client=ig&q=goog,msft

The response is indeed json. There is a good discussion on Stackoverflow about using the first-class Google Finance APIs to get stock quotes here:
[How can I get stock quotes using Google Finance API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/527703/google-financial-api-how-get-stock-quotes)

Comment: Thanks for the comma. I did came across that post, I remember, Anyway there is no real good tutorial, yet, about how to get stockquotes. The current tradevalue, etc. Not straighforward anyway.

Answer (score 1):

comma seperate your sybols.
http://www.google.com/finance/info?client=ig&q=goog,osis

Comment: Thanks, do you also perhaps know what makes the json valid, because I did ltrim($string,'/') to get rid of the forward slashes?

Comment: Someone suggested the slashes are to invalidate the json, forcing you to parse it somehow (as you have done above) as some kind of security thing, but I dunno about that sort of thing :)

Comment: Thanks, I got an associative array I think, I am now reading the php manuel to extract a single value.

Comment: It's an array within an array, I have read that eval is never good, if you can do it in another way. So I will explore that first.