# android using web services for google finance api

Tags: android, web-services, api

I am a newbie to android, and i am really confused as to how to proceed for google finance api through android. Can anyone suggest me some good articles about it? and also how to use web services through android. 
thanks

Comment: My bad : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/527703/how-can-i-get-stock-quotes-using-google-finance-api

Comment: yes. i have seen it but its not very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

finance api url: "http://www.gummy-stuff.org/Yahoo-data.htm"

```
 private static String convertStreamToString(InputStream is) {
/*
 * To convert the InputStream to String we use the
 * BufferedReader.readLine() method. We iterate until the BufferedReader
 * return null which means there's no more data to read. Each line will
 * appended to a StringBuilder and returned as String.
 */
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

String line = null;
try {
    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
        sb.append(line + "\n");
    }
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} finally {
    try {
        is.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
return sb.toString();
}

/*
 * This is a test function which will connects to a given rest service and
* prints it's response to Android Log with labels "Praeda".
 */
public static String[] connect(String url) {
HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
String[] str = new String[5];

// Prepare a request object
HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet(url);

// Execute the request
HttpResponse response;
try {
    response = httpclient.execute(httpget);
    // Examine the response status
    Log.d(TAG, response.getStatusLine().toString());

    // Get hold of the response entity
    HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
    // If the response does not enclose an entity, there is no need
    // to worry about connection release

    if (entity != null) {

        // A Simple JSON Response Read
        InputStream instream = entity.getContent();
        String result = convertStreamToString(instream);
        result=result.replace("parseExchangeRate(", "").replace(");", "");
        Log.d(TAG, result);

        // A Simple JSONObject Creation
        JSONObject json = new JSONObject(result);
        Log.d(TAG, "<jsonobject>\n" + json.toString()
                + "\n</jsonobject>");

        // A Simple JSONObject Parsing
        // JSONArray nameArray=json.names();
        // Log.i("query",nameArray.toString());
        // JSONObject query=json.getJSONObject("query");
        // Log.i("query",query.toString());
        // JSONArray results=query.getJSONArray("results");
        // Log.i("rslts",results.toString());
        // JSONArray quote=results.getJSONArray("quote");
        // JSONObject quote=results.getJSONObject("quote");
        // Log.i("quote",quote.toString());
        JSONObject query = json.getJSONObject("query");
        Log.d(TAG, query.toString());
        JSONObject results = query.getJSONObject("results");
        Log.d(TAG, results.toString());
        JSONObject quote = results.getJSONObject("row");
        Log.d(TAG, quote.toString());
        for (int i = 0; i < quote.length(); i++) {

            // Log.i("Praedafor","<jsonname"+i+">\n"+nameArray.getString(i)+"\n</jsonname"+i+">\n"
            // +"<jsonvalue"+i+">\n"+valArray.getString(i)+"\n</jsonvalue"+i+">");
            // JSONObject quotes = results.getJSONObject(i)
            // .getJSONObject("quote");
            // Log,i
            // Log.i("name",quote.getString("Name"));
            // Log.i("name","pahunch");
            // Log.i("name",quote.getString("Symbol"));

            // Log.i("name",quote.getString("DaysLow"));

            // Log.i("name",quote.getString("DaysHigh"));

            // Log.i("name",quote.getString("Open"));

            // Log.i("name",quote.getString("PreviousClose"));
            String symbol = quote.getString("rate");
            str[0] = symbol;
            String dayslow = quote.getString("DaysLow");
            str[1]=dayslow;
            // tv1.setText(quote.getString("DaysLow"));
            str[2]= quote.getString("DaysHigh");
            str[3]= quote.getString("Open");
            str[4]= quote.getString("Change");
        }

        // A Simple JSONObject Value Pushing
        // json.put("execution-start-time", "sample value");
        Log.d(TAG, "<jsonobject>\n" + json.toString()
                + "\n</jsonobject>");
        // Log.i("Praeda12",json.get("").toString());

        // Closing the input stream will trigger connection release
        instream.close();
    }

} catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
    Log.d(TAG, "ClientProtocolException");
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
    Log.d(TAG, "IOException " + e.getMessage());
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (JSONException e) {
    Log.d(TAG, "JSONException " + e.getMessage());
    e.getMessage();
}
return str;
}
```