# Get Quotes from Google Finance / Yahoo Finance 

Tags: c#, finance

How would I receive a a stock quote onto C#? Google Finance API isn't very helpful

Comment: dupe http://stackoverflow.com/questions/527703/how-can-i-get-stock-quotes-using-google-finance-api

Comment: Perhaps you need to say why the Google Finance API isn't very helpful?

Answer (score 1):

One of the quickest way is to using yahoo http request (some details can be found in see http://www.gummy-stuff.org/Yahoo-data.htm )

Then using the following code to retrieve the result programmatically instead of manual download or using spreadsheet.

```
public static string Extract(string yahooHttpRequestString)
{
      //if need to pass proxy using local configuration  
      System.Net.WebClient webClient = new WebClient();  
      webClient.Proxy = HttpWebRequest.GetSystemWebProxy();  
      webClient.Proxy.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;  

      Stream strm = webClient.OpenRead(yahooHttpRequestString);  
      StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(strm);  
      string result = sr.ReadToEnd();            
      strm.Close();             
      return result;  
}
```

then you can process the returned string further, or modify the above code to parse the string for each segment of the quote, into a more elaborated data structure.

Comment: it is no longer active

Comment: Is there a way to get the list of stock names (not their historical data) by index or country?

Answer (score 1):

**Google Finance API Alternative.** A free, excellent alternative to Google's Finance API is [AlphaVantage](https://www.alphavantage.co/). You can sign up for a free API key to start retrieving live & historical stock market quotes.

**How to retrieve AlphaVantage Stock Market Data using C#?** Here is some sample code to retrieve monthly stock market prices in C#. You will need to install [ServiceStack.Text](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Text) - a free, open-source, high performance .NET text utility to run the below (Install-Package ServiceStack.Text).

```
public class AlphaVantageData
{
      public DateTime Timestamp { get; set; }
      public decimal Open { get; set; }
      public decimal High { get; set; }
      public decimal Low { get; set; }
      public decimal Close { get; set; }
      public decimal Volume { get; set; }
}

// retrieve monthly prices for Microsoft
var symbol = "MSFT";
var apiKey = "demo"; // retrieve your api key from https://www.alphavantage.co/support/#api-key
var monthlyPrices = $"https://www.alphavantage.co/query?function=TIME_SERIES_MONTHLY&symbol={symbol}&apikey={apiKey}&datatype=csv"
                .GetStringFromUrl().FromCsv<List<AlphaVantageData>>();

monthlyPrices.PrintDump();
```

You can run above sample code in gistlyn [here](https://gistlyn.com/?gist=099fff06d515a39964932e6eafded243). 
I have written a full article "AlphaVantage and C#" [here](https://medium.com/@mark.holdt/alphavantage-and-c-1d560e690387).

Comment: Note that the free version of AlphaVantage has a daily request limit of 20 requests which makes it rather useless

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to go through [Stock quote from Yahoo! in C#](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/37550/Stock-quote-and-chart-from-Yahoo-in-C) article to access stock quote from Yahoo......