# Is there a way in C# to get a 'browser' to pre-process a WebRequest so you can work with the elements that you see when you 'View Source'

Tags: c#, httprequest, webrequest, stocks

I want to make a webrequest to e.g. http://finance.yahoo.com/q?s=rb.l and extract the share price. However the text returned is before the browser has processed it and I need it processed first before the `<span></span>` element exists that I need to look for.

Is this possible, or should I be looking at doing it another way?

Similarly any reliable 15-min delayed free stock service for the LSE or other way of obtaining this data given just the ticker code would be great.

Comment: How does the `WebRequest` class relate to an actual browser?

Comment: By "process" do you mean "execute JavaScript"?  If so, then no.  What you're talking about is a web browser, which does a _lot_ more than make simple HTTP requests (which is what a webrequest does).

Comment: is this a local (winforms/wpf) app or a web app?

Comment: Are you sure that the screen scraping you're attempting to do doesn't violate Yahoo's terms of service?

Comment: Yes I mean execute all the client side code, I'm doing this until I can find another way to get stock prices. I'm not sure about the Yahoo ToS I will check

Answer (score 1):

There are two questions here: first, how to programmatically access data on a page after allowing javascripts and such to run on that page as if it were being read by a real browser. Secondly, how to get stock ticker information programmatically.

To answer the first question: You could use something like WebDriver .NET to literally instantiate a browser that opens the page, and then access elements on the page.

To answer the second question, I suggest you try to [search for that question directly](https://www.google.com/search?q=stock%20quote%20service%20api), since it's a common enough problem that you'll probably find [a number of people](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/527703/how-can-i-get-stock-quotes-using-google-finance-api) who have answered it already.

Comment: Thanks - yes I didn't really mean to add the 'second' question that was really just putting it in context. I will look at WebDriver to see if this will work and post back