# HighChart.js data source recommendations

Tags: api, highcharts, stock

I am looking to use Highstock.js for an application I am developing and looking to implement a stock performance with Highcharts stock library chart; http://www.highcharts.com/stock/demo/

I was wondering if there was any good suggestions on where to get the data source from?

Thank-you!

Answer (score 1):

I fetch data from an API, and then store the data in localstorage.

e.g:

This fetches data from an API for use with Highcharts, and stores/updates it in localstorage (jStorage).

```
    updateLocalStorage: function(id) {
        //Check if local storage needs updating
        if (isNaN($.jStorage.get(id))) {
            //Data exists in Localstorage, merge data
            //Query API for highstock data

            return $.post('api/', {
                data_id: id
            }, function(data) {
                if (data) {
                    var merged = $.extend($.jStorage.get(id), data);
                    $.jStorage.set(id, merged);
                }
            });

            //return true;
        }
}
```

Once this data has been fetched I then render highcharts from the data that is stored in localstorage.

```
$.when(updateLocalStorage(id)).then(function(response){               
if(response){
//Local storage is up to date. Render chart
}
});
```

I can also fetch data from the API using a timer and update localstorage, when I want to re-render the chart I can just use the highcharts setData method, e.g:

```
var json = $.jStorage.get(id);

for(i =0; i < json.data; i++) {
    chart_object.series[i].setData(json.data[i]);
}
```

Comment: Thanks StuR, I am using xIgnite for my data source, http://www.xignite.com really nice API with minimal clean up required for Highstocks

Answer (score 0):

You can hardcode data in series / data object as in the example http://www.highcharts.com/demo/ Obviously you can also use dynamically way to define points.

http://docs.highcharts.com/#preprocessing

Answer (score 0):

If you are asking about where to get financial stock price data from, there are several sources I know of including google finance and yahoo finance. Here are some links to help you:

[How can I get stock quotes using Google Finance API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/527703/how-can-i-get-stock-quotes-using-google-finance-api)

http://www.yqlblog.net/blog/2009/06/02/getting-stock-information-with-yql-and-open-data-tables/